# Is it possible to create a collaborative network?

Tags: hardware

My problem, I have a hotel in a remote area, with many guests and a lot of Internet use.

Is there a way to use Internet from different sources and combine it to increase the total network speed? Maybe using a network switch to direct traffic needs?

Comment: I thought of buying two different Internet connection lines and using those to increase my network bandwidth. Is this possible?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Comment: Keep in mind if you use a bunch of slow connections and balance between then no single device with get more bandwidth than the connection it's using at that time. If you have 2 1mb circuits and balance traffic between them a single computer will never see more than 1mb with most solutions. I don't know of any that can truly combine them to a single 2mb circuit but that doesn't mean it's not out there. Even aggregated interfaces balance between the connections.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of solutions on market. I would check if any of your local ISPs support line bonding. That would be ideal option.

Comment: So if I purchase 10 different Internet connections with 10 different modems from a service provider, I can in theory increase the Internet speed of 10 different users to be about the same? While they are only virtually being connected to the same network?

Comment: I believe this model only supports two WAN connections.

Comment: Are there different models or network switches or any other hardware that can do the same thing for 5-10 different connections? Is it a common solution to the problem I am having?

Comment: Product recommendations are explicitly off-topic here, as are consumer-grade devices.

Comment: Why don't you just get a faster link.... any ISP offering to install 10 connections, will surely install a 10x faster single connection for you and presumably it will be cheaper...

Answer (score 1):

You can't solve this with a switch but you can use a router supporting multiple WAN uplinks and then set up traffic rules for splitting the traffic (by user IP, service, load, ...).

Alternatively, as a very simple setup, you can set up multiple LANs with one router and uplink each.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not bonding links from several providers. You are in the middle of nowhere, or remote, as you put it. There's not going to be several providers out there.  You simply need a single bigger/better link.

Answer (score 0):

As @datagram network pointed out there are several ways to do this.
One of them might be to use just a single ISP and request a very high bandwidth add various access points.

Else you can subscribe to multiple ISP's i.e get multiple addresses for yourself and then divide the use among people eg. management and customer.
This would also ensure reliability in case of connection failure from one ISP.

Another not so good approach would be reduce the speed of the router links such that no particular set of users thwart the entire bandwidth

Comment: Any hardware keywords suggestions that I can search on google and come up with relevant products?

Comment: i think identifying relevant providers and speaking to them about your needs would be more appropriate unless you wish to read the specs sheet of the router and decide yourself

Comment: relevant providers of routers? Or what exactly do you mean?

Comment: ISP - Internet Service Providers. I would firstly get touch with them and see what they can offer at yours location.

Answer (score -3):

Switches can be a valuable asset to networking. Overall, they can increase the capacity and speed of your network. However, switching should not be seen as a cure-all for network issues. Before incorporating network switching, you must first ask yourself two important questions: First, how can you tell if your network will benefit from switching? Second, how do you add switches to your network design to provide the most benefit?

Here's something I read about switches, might help.

https://www.lantronix.com/resources/networking-tutorials/network-switching-tutorial/